# Prove that $1+x<e^x$ for all real numbers $x\neq0$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Prove that $1+x<e^x$ for all real numbers $x\neq0$.

Here is my solution:

We'll prove this as two cases; first when $x<0$ and then when $x>0$.

Let $\alpha>0$. Then,
$$e^\alpha-\alpha e^\alpha<1\Rightarrow e^\alpha(1-\alpha)<1\Rightarrow1-\alpha<\frac{1}{e^\alpha}\Rightarrow1-\alpha<e^{-\alpha}.$$ 
Setting $x=-\alpha$ gives the desired result. Next, consider the fact that $0<\ln(e^\alpha-\alpha)$, as natural log is a strictly positive function. Then,
$$0<\ln(e^\alpha-\alpha)\Rightarrow\ln(1)<\ln(e^\alpha-\alpha)\Rightarrow1<e^\alpha-\alpha\Rightarrow1+\alpha<e^\alpha.$$
Setting $x=\alpha$ gives the desired result.

I believe this is a valid proof, but this question is asked in the context of a calculus course, so I'm wondering if there is a different/better way to solve this.

Comment: If you've learned taylor series, you could just expand $\exp(x)$ to the 1st degree, including the always positive error term $O(x^2)$. If not, then that method seems fine.

Comment: If you graph 1+x and e^x, you'll see that e^x is greater than or equal to 1+x, with the functions tangent at x=0. Since you said it is a calculus argument, you can make this rigorous by considering the difference in derivatives between the functions. 

What do you mean by natural log being a strictly positive function? log(.5) = -.693, for example. I think you go wrong there in your proof.

Comment: What makes you claim that $e^\alpha-\alpha e^\alpha<1$ holds for all $\alpha>0$ in the first place? Of course it *is* true because it is equivalent to $1-\alpha<e^{-\alpha}$ (or, in other words, that $1+x<e^x$ holds for all $x<0$), which is a special case of what you need to prove. But you have not proved it.

Comment: @user196574 Ah, you're right. I need to argue that $\mbox{ln}(e^\alpha-\alpha)$ is non-negative in a different way.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Well, $e^\alpha>0$ and $\alpha e^\alpha>0$, so clearly $e^\alpha-\alpha e^\alpha<1$.

Comment: @Atsina "Well, $35>0$ and $19>0$, so clearly $35-19<1$."

Comment: Let $f(x) = e^x-x-1$. Then $f'(x) = e^x-1$ and $f'(x) = 0 \implies x=0$. Also $f''(0) = 0$, hence $f(x) \ge 0$; since the equality is achieved at the minimum point at $x =0$ you have $f(x) > 0$ for $x \ne 0$.

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Okay, I get what you're trying to say, but this is a false analogy. I see that it should be $\leq$ and that I need to elaborate on why that is true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,  $e^x$ is increasing, 
which is easy to see by computing the derivative.

For $x\gt0$:  $\ln(1+x)\lt x\iff\int_1^{1+x}\frac1tdt\lt x\cdot \frac11$ just by considering an upper Riemann sum with **one** subinterval.

For $-1\lt x\lt0$:  $-\ln(1+x)= \int_{1+x}^1\frac1tdt\gt -x\cdot\frac11$, using a lower sum, and the same result follows.

For $x\le -1$, it's obvious, since $e^x\gt0$.

Answer (score 4):

As @Shinalord stated clearly, $\forall x>0$:

$$e^x = 1+x+ \underbrace{\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+O\left(x^4\right)}_{>0} > 1 + x$$

Here's a graph:

[image]

Comment: Does the original question not also require the other case $x<0$?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=e^x-x-1$. Then $f'(x)=e^x-1$ and $f''(x)=e^x$. Clearly $f''(x)\gt0$ for all $x$ and $f'(0)=0$, so $f$ has an absolute minimum at $x=0$. I.e., if $x\not=0$, then $f(x)\gt f(0)=0$. Thus $e^x\gt x+1$ for all $x\not=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By Taylor's formula, $$e^x=1+x+\frac{e^\xi}{2}\cdot x^2,$$where $0 \gtrless \xi \gtrless x.$
Hence $$e^x-1-x=\frac{e^\xi}{2}\cdot x^2>0,\forall x \neq 0$$which implies $$e^x>1+x, \forall x \neq 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

Show that $y=x+1$ is a tangent line to the graph of $f(x)=e^x$ in the point $(0,1)$

and since $f$ is a convex function, we are done!